# Blackberry 10 compiling error

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I get the following error:

```
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/bits.o] Error 1  MyProjectD C/C++ Problem
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....    MyProjectD          C/C++ Problem
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/buffer.o] Error 1    MyProjectD          C/C++ Problem
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/cb_search.o] Error 1 MyProjectD          C/C++ Problem
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2    MyProjectD          C/C++ Problem
make: *** [Simulator-Debug] Error 2 MyProjectD          C/C++ Problem
```

Could anyone help me?

Deployment Failed: Info: Obtained qconn connection
Info: Begin device to host file sync
Info: All files already in sync
Info: File sync complete in 5ms
Info: Sending request: LAUNCH
Info: Action: Launch
Info: Debug native: on
Info: Launching com.example.MyProjectD.testDev_ndRecorderD68e1ff28...
result::Invalid
Info: done

New log:

compilation terminated.
cc: /Applications/development/Momentics.app/host_10_2_0_15/darwin/x86/usr/lib/gcc/i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0/4.6.3/cc1 error 1
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/bits.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1: error: one or more PCH files were found, but they were invalid
cc1: error: use -Winvalid-pch for more information
cc1: fatal error: o-g/.obj/MyProjectD: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc: /Applications/development/Momentics.app/host_10_2_0_15/darwin/x86/usr/lib/gcc/i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0/4.6.3/cc1 error 1
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/buffer.o] Error 1
cc1: error: one or more PCH files were found, but they were invalid
cc1: error: use -Winvalid-pch for more information
cc1: fatal error: o-g/.obj/MyProjectD: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc: /Applications/development/Momentics.app/host_10_2_0_15/darwin/x86/usr/lib/gcc/i486-pc-nto-qnx8.0.0/4.6.3/cc1 error 1
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/cb_search.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make: *** [Simulator-Debug] Error 2

Comment: I'm afraid nobody here will be able to guess the actual error(s) hiding behind `C/C++ Problem`. Is this the only information `make` gives you?

Comment: Try to create a project which produces this error which is as short as possible and add the source code you were using [edit your post to do so].

Comment: I added some additional info about error

Comment: Add the compiler output. It does not help to show deployment comments if the compile did not even finish.

Comment: I have added commpilier log above.

Comment: I think the main problem here:

make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/bits.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs...
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/buffer.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [o-g/.obj/cb_search.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
make: *** [Simulator-Debug] Error 2